# Publishing ArcGIS WMTS for non Esri clients?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, wmts

We use Arcgis 10.4.1 products (Server, desktop). When we publish a service with 
(Google - bing tiling scheme) caching capabilities we can use service in esri clients (JS SDK, Arcmap etc.) but can not use in clients like openlayers. Tiles are shown in completely wrong order.

What should we do to fix this?

Comment: It could be a client side misconfigurition. WMTS is placing the tile origin at different corner than Google or Bing.